# Put results into a group of 2, or any number I specify

Tags: sql, grouping

I need a way to put results into # of groups that I specify.

I have tried `ntile()` function, which I thought would use but it's not working:

```sql
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 1 as Number
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Number+1
  FROM CTE 
  WHERE Number < 100 
)
SELECT *, ntile(80) over (order by number desc) as 'test'
 FROM CTE
```

For the expected results, the Quartile column should output a number for every 2 entries (as specified in `NTILE(80)`), but it can be 2, 4, 10, or any number I specify.

Maybe `NTILE()` is not the right function but is there a function that does what I want?

So, if I specify 3, then the result should group every 3 records. If I specify 15, then the result should group every 15 records and move onto next group.

Hope I'm being clear

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using

Answer (score 1):

> ...should output a number for every 2 entries...

No, you have 100 entries and you want to divide them in 80 groups. You'll get some groups with 1 entry and other groups with 2 entries.

Read the definition of `NTILE()`. If you want groups with 2 entries you can do it as shown below by dividing it in `50` groups:

```
WITH recursive
CTE AS (
  SELECT 1 as Number
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Number + 1
  FROM CTE 
  WHERE Number < 100 
)
SELECT *, 
  ntile(50) -- changed here
  over (order by number desc) as test
FROM CTE
```

You didn't say what database engine you are using, so I assumed PostgreSQL.

Comment: Building on top of this, CEILING(@NUMBER_LIMIT / @GROUP_COUNT) should be passed to ntile to parameterize the described behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply want the modulus operator:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 1 as Number
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Number+1
  FROM CTE 
  WHERE Number < 100 
)
SELECT cte.*, 
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number DESC) - 1) % 3  -- or however many groups that you want
FROM CTE
```